# Having a problem generate XCframework with Kotlin Multiplatform in Mac OS Ventura with Mac M1

Tags: macos, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've already updated my Mac to Mac OS Ventura, but when the update come in the problems with all my projects still starting. For example I have Kotlin MultiplatForm Project but when I try to compile a XCFramework with this task "assembleSharedCodeReleaseXCFramework" the console gets this error

Android Studio Version: **Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1**

```
Compilation failed: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm

* Source files: 
* Compiler version info: Konan: 1.5.31 / Kotlin: 1.5.31
* Output kind: FRAMEWORK
```

This is another response from the console.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class llvm.llvm
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$contextLLVMSetupPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$contextLLVMSetupPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:62)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:333)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:332)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:16)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:332)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:532)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:62)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:62)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:17)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.daemonMain(main.kt:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.runInProcess(KotlinToolRunner.kt:128)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.run(KotlinToolRunner.kt:77)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinNativeCompile.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:349)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeLink.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:679)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:491)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:474)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:174)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:85)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: I don't have an answer, but 1.5.31 is pretty old right now. Also, M1 support had recently been added, so it could have some old, since fixed, bugs: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/07/kotlin-1-5-30-m1-released/

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue after upgrading Mac OS to Ventura. Upgrading to kotlin Version 1.7.20 from 1.5.32 fixed the issue.